# Transform column data based on row entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table

| Region | Variable | Audi | Porsche |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Australia | Orders | 5000 | **20** |
| Australia | Price | 50000 | 100000 |
| Australia | Color | red | green |
| France | Orders | **99** | 100 |
| France | Price | 50000 | 100000 |
| France | Color | white | blue |

based on the column where `Variable Orders < 100` all other entries for this car should be `0`.

| Region | Variable | Audi | Porsche |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Australia | Orders | 5000 | 20 |
| Australia | Price | 50000 | 0 |
| Australia | Color | red | 0 |
| France | Orders | 99 | 100 |
| France | Price | 0 | 100000 |
| France | Color | 0 | blue |

I tried to split the table by `Region` and used `where =` but could not get to any result here. I do not even know how it could be accomplished so it would be great if you could help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of aggregation here to efficiently generate a boolean true/false flag for each. note this also has to use `try_convert` since the columns are presumably `varchar` in a sort of EAV model.

```
with x as (
    select *, 
        Max(case when variable='orders' and Try_Convert(int,audi)>=100 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by region) showAudi,
        Max(case when variable='orders' and Try_Convert(int,porsche)>=100 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by region) showPorsche
    from t
)
select Region, Variable,
    case when variable='Orders' or ShowAudi=1    then Audi    else '0' end Audi,
    case when variable='Orders' or ShowPorsche=1 then Porsche else '0' end Porsche
from x
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c07e4ba5dd4b064100099b2a031392fe)

Comment: The code does what it has to. Perfect, thanks a lot!!
I have one question since I do not understand for what the Max() function is here. We check if orders and audi is >= 100 and if so assign a 1 otherwise a 0. So what is the Max() for? It is not like there is a 1 and a 0 and we have to choose the highest. My guess it is actually redundant but needed for the over() but this is just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
  SELECT 
    a.Region,
    a.Variable,
    CASE WHEN a.Variable <> 'Orders' AND EXISTS(SELECT null FROM t z WHERE a.Region = z.Region AND 'Orders' = z.Variable AND TRY_PARSE(z.Audi AS INT) < 100) THEN '0' ELSE Audi END AS Audi,
    CASE WHEN a.Variable <> 'Orders' AND EXISTS(SELECT null FROM t z WHERE a.Region = z.Region AND 'Orders' = z.Variable AND TRY_PARSE(z.Porsche as INT) < 100) THEN '0' ELSE Porsche END AS Porsche
  FROM
    t a
```

You can also form a sub-query of just those Orders rows and join it in then you have a constant comparable on each row:

```
SELECT 
    a.Region,
    a.Variable,
    CASE WHEN a.Variable <> 'Orders' AND ords.Audi < 100 THEN '0' ELSE a.Audi END AS Audi,
    CASE WHEN a.Variable <> 'Orders' AND ords.Porsche < 100 THEN '0' ELSE a.Porsche END AS Porsche
  FROM
    t a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM t z WHERE z.Variable = 'Orders') ords ON a.Region = ords.Region
```